# Freetile Jquery plugin - Function not executed when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm Using the [Freetile Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/yconst/Freetile) to make a better looking grid.
On my webpage i have like cards that are different in height so thats why i am using the freetile.

**Problem**
This is my jQuery snippet for the execution of the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#freetile-container').freetile({ animate: true, elementDelay: 30 });
});

</script>
```

It doesn't execute the plugin so my page looks like this
[Image - only floated](http://oi50.tinypic.com/2dl2olu.jpg)

But when i bring up my firebug , suddnely the plugin is executed and the "cards" are animated and tiled along each other. [Image - Now tiled](http://oi47.tinypic.com/2rqghnc.jpg)

I can't really figure out what seems to be wrong - does jquery think that my page hasn't loaded yet or something?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Having the exact same problem, it seems the ordering of the tiles are only done after resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a custom element selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#freetile-container').freetile({ 
        selector: '.post',
        animate: true, 
        elementDelay: 30
    });
});
```

*Replace "post" by the class name of your element.*